# ES6 style import for cesium

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cesiumjs, javascript-import

I am running with Chrome V61, which has native ES6 support.

I am getting an error when I do:

```
import Cesium from '../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js';

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'default'
```

The module is included in html file with:

```
 <script type="module" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Perhaps it is not compatible with ES6 modules, but it there any chance I can shim this?

Full code:

```
import Cesium from '../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js';

console.log("I'm the entry point");

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
```

Comment: If you look at the network inspector? Are you sure it is loading the correct file, and it is actually ES6? Seems like your `../` for instance would move out of your `scripts` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cesium is a node.js module, which means it uses the node.js module syntax of `module.exports`, rather than the ES6 module specification of `export default { }`. In order to use Cesium with ES6 on the front-end, you'll need something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), which will the allow you to use `import Cesium from 'cesium'`.

Comment: It's CommonJS module.

Answer (score 0):

As dcr24 said in his answer, you can use Cesium with Webpack.

**Install Cesium**

```
npm install --save-dev cesium
```

**Configure Cesium in Webpack**

In webpack.config.js

```
// The path to the Cesium source code
const cesiumSource = 'node_modules/cesium/Source';
const cesiumWorkers = '../Build/Cesium/Workers';
```

Next, we’ll add the following options to our configuration object in order to resolve some quirks with how webpack compiles Cesium.

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),

    // Needed to compile multiline strings in Cesium
    sourcePrefix: ''
},
amd: {
    // Enable webpack-friendly use of require in Cesium
    toUrlUndefined: true
},
node: {
    // Resolve node module use of fs
    fs: 'empty'
},
```

Next let’s add a cesium alias so we can easily reference it in our application code like a traditional Node module.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        // Cesium module name
        cesium: path.resolve(__dirname, cesiumSource)
    }
},
```

**Manage Cesium static files**

Lastly, let’s make sure the static Cesium asset, widget, and web worker files are being served and loaded correctly.

```
npm install --save-dev copy-webpack-plugin
```

Then require it near the top of our webpack.config.js file.

```
const CopywebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
```

Additionally, add the following to the plugins array.

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    // Copy Cesium Assets, Widgets, and Workers to a static directory
    new CopywebpackPlugin([ { from: path.join(cesiumSource, cesiumWorkers), to: 'Workers' } ]),
    new CopywebpackPlugin([ { from: path.join(cesiumSource, 'Assets'), to: 'Assets' } ]),
    new CopywebpackPlugin([ { from: path.join(cesiumSource, 'Widgets'), to: 'Widgets' } ])
],
```

We’re copying the Assets and Widgets directories as-is. Additionally we’ll use the built web worker scripts, which have already been compiled and optimized with the RequireJS optimizer. Since the web workers are designed to run separately in their own thread, they can be loaded and run as-is. The web workers rarely, if ever, will be needed in their original form for debugging. We’ll copy these over from the Build/Cesium/Workers directory.

Lastly, we’ll define an environment variable that tells Cesium the base URL at which to load static files using the DefinePlugin that’s built into webpack. The plugins array will now look like this:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    // Copy Cesium Assets, Widgets, and Workers to a static directory
    new CopywebpackPlugin([ { from: path.join(cesiumSource, cesiumWorkers), to: 'Workers' } ]),
    new CopywebpackPlugin([ { from: path.join(cesiumSource, 'Assets'), to: 'Assets' } ]),
    new CopywebpackPlugin([ { from: path.join(cesiumSource, 'Widgets'), to: 'Widgets' } ]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        // Define relative base path in cesium for loading assets
        CESIUM_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify('')
    })
],
```

**Require Cesium modules in our app**

CommonJS style

To require all of the Cesium libraries under one object:

```
var Cesium = require('cesium/Cesium');
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
```

To require an individual module:

```
var Color = require('cesium/Core/Color');
var color = Color.fromRandom();
```

ES6 style import

To require all of the Cesium library under one object:

```
import Cesium from 'cesium/Cesium';
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
```

To require an individual module:

```
import Color from 'cesium/core/Color';
var color = Color.fromRandom();
```

More detailed information can be found in this tutorial [Cesium and Webpack](https://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/cesium-and-webpack/).

A sample of code can be found in the oficial repository [Cesium Webpack Example](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium-webpack-example)